# Why is my shortcode not working

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

Im making a custom shortcode for my wordpress site and im just running through the example from the shortcode api for wordpress:

```
function myshortcode() {

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'custom_title' => 'Your Title',
        'custom_message' => 'Your Message',
    ), $atts);

    return 'Test: ' . $atts['custom_title'] . ' ' . $atts['custom_message'];

}

add_shortcode('my-short','myshortcode');
```

The shortcode in my blog post is:

```
[my-short custom_title="Test" custom_message="123 Roman Ridge"]
```

but it outputs

```
Test: Your Title Your Message
```

there is nothing else in my blog post except the shortcode, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the following line in your function defintion:

```
function myshortcode() {
```

it's missing the input parameters `$atts` and `$content` so that's why you only get the default attribute values.

Replace it with:

```
function myshortcode( $atts = [], $content = '' ) {
```